# Google Docs and different first site header or Sections in Google Docs...?

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Is there any way **to push release** of **different first page headers** or **creating doc sections of styles** to the **Google Docs?**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have enough control of Google Docs to do those things with google-drive-sdk.

There are two workarounds I can think of.

1. Get export link from [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) and export it as known format (.doc, .pdf, etc)
2. Use Google AppsScript [Document Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/). You can have some control over header.